# Wanted: .Net collection that stores a bunch of case insensitive strings fast and efficient

Tags: c#, .net, collections, generics

I'm looking for a simple collection that will store a bunch of strings in **a case insensitive** way. I need at least a `Contains()` and `Remove()` method to see if a certain string is present and to remove that string.

I've tried `List<string>` but that one is case sensitive. I need could use a case insensitive `Dictionary<TKey, T>`, but that "feels" like a waste of space. Doing a `ToLower()` on each string is a waste of performance.

Does anyone know what kind .Net collection I should use?

Comment: When you say "a bunch of strings", how many are we talking about?

Comment: You can use a List as you previously attempted and pass in StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase as SLaks stated when calling Contains

Comment: +/- 10k of items and I'll need to quiz this collection quite frequently.

Comment: Consider storing lowercase strings, instead of doing case-insensitive comparisons. This will likely be faster still.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use a `new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.
Note that this is an unordered set.

Comment: What are the perfomance implication of an unordered set. Is there an ordered version out there?

Comment: Unordered collections will always be faster than their ordered counterparts, because of the more lax requirements.

Comment: The documentation says Contains and Remove are an O(1) operations.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383091%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: +1. Note that Dictionary also provides the same constructor "public Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)" with similar performance - you can switch to it if need to associate data with strings. There is no need to do ToUpperInvariant (never ToLower) before putting either of them.

Comment: Do you have an .Net 2.0 alternative?

Comment: @Kees: You could use a `StringDictionary` and waste values.

Comment: You could also add a reference to System.Core, perhaps from Mono.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`StringDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary.aspx).

Comment: Sure, I guess if you are not keying with text that is different from the text inserting maybe it's not appropriate.

Comment: we still have the problem of the double values in memory.

Comment: @SLaks: Wish I could spend all available up-votes on your comment; hope it was supposed to sound witty, too...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem to solve today. If you can include Linq, then your List gets overloaded methods with a comparer.

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Contains("hello", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Hope this helps:
Martin

Comment: Unfortunately LINQ is 3.5 and I'm developing for 2.0. The problem with your solution is that the contains will take O(N) and I'm missing a remove function. It seems the HashSet<string> will give the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

By default Dictionary are not case in-sensitive. But you can implement your own variant to make it in-sensitive. (I might be wrong on this :D)

I had same issue with Dictionary but then after trying a lot of IEquality implementations, finally I settled the score with LINQ.

```
string k = customers.Where(c => c.Key.Equals(valueToSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault().Key;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(k) && k.ToUpper() == valueToSearch.ToUpper())
{
    // Do some thing
}
```

Hope this will help somebody in future.

Sanjay Zalke

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The problem with the dictionary is that you have a key / value pair. I only need to know if the string is present. There is no need for the 'value' part. So using a dictionary would waste memory space.

Comment: Hi Kees, This implementation is not at all related just to Dictionary, but it is LINQ so it applied to all objects in .net including Databases. If you have list use : [code](string k = customers.Where(c => c.Equals(valueToSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();)

Comment: Ah got it. Problem is that I'm using .Net 2.0. It still seems that 'new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)' is the fastest as it is O(1). Your code uses a for, which makes it O(N).

Answer (score -1):

Write your own `Contains()` and `Remove()` methods, which perform the case insensitve comparison.

Comment: How is your solution faster than the HashSet<string> that has been suggested?

Comment: Contains extension method which takes a comparer already exists in the framework.

Comment: A HashSet will be much faster than any other option.

Comment: Guess I missed the point in the OPs question about speed. I must have been posting my solution at the same time you were posting yours. I guess I'll ammend the comment, "It isn't faster."